# How to design a Routemap for a given map

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, location

this is Bangalore Metro Map.

[image: Bangalore Metro Route]

Now I am designing an app that should tell the user the number of stops between a source and a destination. Now suppose the user has to go from one stop in blue line to other in the blue line only. As in this image..

[image: Travelling from BlueLine to BlueLine]

Now as we can see it should say thar boarding point will be 1, and destination will be 2 and there are 6 stops in between. How to calculate the number of stops in between and also the distance. And what if the line changes, that is the user wants to travel from BlueLine to YellowLine.

I have the name of stops in the form of a string array for each line.. Here is the array..

```
 String[] greenline = {"Bangalore International Exhibition Center", "Jindal", "Manjunathnagar", "Nagasandra", "Dasarahalli", "Jalahalli", "Peenya Industry", "Peenya", "Yeswanthpur Industry", "Yeswanthpur", "Sandal Soap Factory", "Mahalaxmi", "Rajajinagar", "Kuvempu Road", "Srirampura", "Sampige Road", "Kempegowda Interchange", "Chikpet", "K R Market", "National College", "Lalbagh", "South End Circle", "Jayanagar", "R V Road Interchange", "Banashankari", "J P Nagar", "Puttenahalli", "Anjanapura Cross Road", "Krishna Leela Park", "Vajrahalli", "Thaighattapura", "Anjanapura/NICE Junction"};

String[] blueline = {"Kengeri", "R V College of Engineering", "Bangalore University Cross", "Rajarajeshwari Nagar", "Nayandahalli", "Mysore Road", "Deepanjali Nagar", "Attiguppe", "Vijayanagar", "Hosahall1i", "Magadi Road", "City Railway Station", "Kempegowda Interchange", "Sir M Vishweshwariah", "Vidhana Soudha", "Cubbon Park", "M G Road Interchange", "Trinity", "Halasuru", "Indiranagar", "S V Road", "Baiyyappanahalli", "Jyotipura", "K R Puram", "Mahadevpura", "Garudacharpalya", "Doddanekkundi Induatrial State", "Vishweshwariah Industrial State", "Kundanahalli", "Vydhehi Hospital", "Satya Sai Medical Institute", "ITPB", "Kadugodi Industrial Area", "Ujjwal Vidhyalaya", "Whitefield"};

String[] redline = {"Nagawara", "Arabic College", "Venkateshpura", "Tannery Town", "Pottery Town", "Cantonment Railway Station", "Shivajinagar", "M G Road Interchange", "Vellara Junction", "Langford Town", "Mico Bosch", "Dairy Circle", "Swagath Road Cross", "Jayadeva Hospital Interchange", "J P Nagar 4th Phase", "IIMB", "Hulimavu", "Gottigere"};

String[] yellowline = {"R V Road Interchange", "Ragigudda Temple", "Jayadeva hospital Interchange", "BTM Layout", "Silk Board", "HSR Layout", "Oxford College", "Muneshwara Nagar", "Chikkabegur", "Basapura Road", "Hosa Road", "Electronics City 1", "Electronics City 2", "Huskur Road", "Hebbagodi", "Bommasandra"};
```

Someone please help. Thanx in advance.

Comment: look into A*, or Dijkstra. The rest is routine.

Comment: Pardon..!!..?? What.?

Comment: A* and Dijkstra's algorithm describe how to find the shortest path in a graph. I assume that is what you're fighting with.

Comment: Can you please give me an answer with example. I really need it.

Comment: Example of what? An example implementation of A*?

Comment: Yes how to Implement that here. Please..

Comment: Does the example implementation on Wikipedia not suffice? If so, why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39041/discussion-between-akshat-and-jan-dvorak)

Answer (score 2):

Start by converting the list of lines into a graph that you'll be searching through.

- let each node hold its name, a list of edges and its distance from source (initially infinity), and the previous node in the best path
- let each edge hold both nodes, the line it belongs to and its cost.
- prepare a hash map of strings to nodes, called "nodes"
- prepare a set of nodes, called "transfer nodes". You may use a hash map string (name) => node for this.
- for each line:

  - if "nodes" has no entry for the first station of the line, create a new node and add it to "nodes".
  - for each station except the first one:

    - if "nodes" has no entry for this station, create a new node and add it to "nodes".
    - create a new edge joining this station and the previous station. Its cost is unity.
    - add this edge to the list of edges for both stations
    - if either node belongs to more than one line now (lookup succeeded), add this station to "transfer nodes".

(note: since your lines are stored in a set of variables, you could perform "each line" as follows:)

```
private HashMap<Node> nodes;
private void addLine (String[] stops, String name){...};
// ... ( ... ){ ...
addLine(greenline, "green line");
addLine(blueline,  "blue line" );
//...
```

if transfer costs are nonzero, add transfer costs:

- for each node in "transfer nodes":

  - for each line that uses the node:

    - create a new node, named after the original one.
    - redirect all (one or both) edges for that line to the new node - change their source or destination and add them to the new node edge list.
  - for each pair of new station nodes

    - create a new edge joining them, and add this edge to the edge list of both nodes. Its cost is the transfer cost.

Now, find the cheapest path from the source to the destination. I'll show the Dijkstra's algorithm:

- prepare a priority queue of nodes, called "open set". If the transfer cost is zero or one, you can use an ordinary queue for this.
- add the source node to the "open set". If the start station is a transfer station, add all associated nodes to the "open set".
- set the source node distance from the source to be zero
- repeat

  - pop a node called "from" from the "open set". It is an error if no such element exists.
    if the node corresponds to the destination station, break the loop, remembering "from".
  - for each neighbour of this node, called "to":

    - calculate the new distance for "to". It is the distance for "from" plus the length of the connecting edge
    - if the new distance is shorter than the current distance for "to":

      - update the distance for "to".
      - update the leading edge of "to" to be the edge between "from" and "to".
      - if the distance was infinity, add "to" to the "open set"
      - else update the position of "to" in the "open set"
- collect the edges along the best path:
- start with an empty list of edges
- let the current node be "from".
- while the current node has a previous edge defined:

  - else add the previous edge to the list of edges
  - let the current node be the other node on this edge

now what's left is to read the path:

- initialise the edge counter to 1
- for each edge in the list of edges:

  - if this is the first edge, output "start by travelling `edge.line` from `start`".
  - else if the previous edge is a transfer edge, output "after `count` stops, transfer to `edge.line` at `prevEdge.node[0].name`" and reset the edge counter.
  - else increment the edge counter.
- output "after `%count` stops, exit at `%target`".